# Reverse Engineer Video File Format

Tags: digital-forensics, binary-format

I have recorded a video from a set top box which I am not able to see on my computer/laptop. I have already tried multiple video converter softwares and converting it too. 
Please !! I would really appreciate if someone could help me in watching and decoding and reverse engineer this file format. Also, I dont know which tags to include in this question. If somebody could suggest some tags, I would change it accordingly.

You can get the file here (8 MB only, a small recording)
https://www.dropbox.com/s/5d62xkm1kj4sq7p/193135ZEE%20CLASSIC0.mpg?dl=0

Answer (score 9):

The first byte of the file is `0x47`, [which suggests](http://www.garykessler.net/library/file_sigs.html) that it's an [MPEG transport stream](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MPEG_transport_stream).

I used [010 Editor](http://www.sweetscape.com/010editor/) to create the following template for the file to parse it as an array of [Partial Transport Stream Packets](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MPEG_transport_stream#Packet):

```
typedef struct {
    BYTE sync_byte <format=hex>;
    WORD transport_error_indicator : 1;
    WORD payload_unit_start_indicator : 1;
    WORD transport_priority : 1;
    WORD pid : 13;
    enum <BYTE> SCRAMBLE { not_scrambled=0, reserved=1, even_key=2, odd_key=3 } scrambling_control : 2;
    BYTE adaptation_field_exist : 1;
    BYTE contains_payload : 1;
    BYTE continuity_counter : 4;
    BYTE payload_data[188-4];
} TS_PACKET;

TS_PACKET packets[FileSize()/sizeof(TS_PACKET)];
```

Applying the above template to the file yields the following results:
[image: 010 Editor]

As you can see above (circled in red), each packet's payload is encrypted with a [DVB-CSA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Common_Scrambling_Algorithm) key. So it would appear that you would need that key in order to be able to decrypt the video stream's data.

Comment: @Akhilesh [This](https://www.cdc.informatik.tu-darmstadt.de/~jwaelde/breaking-dvbcsa.pdf) pdf document explains dvb-csa encryption and ways to attack it.